# A volume form on the sphere which gives equal areas to all hemispheres is the standard one?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, volume, differential-forms, symmetry, spheres

Let $\omega$ be a volume form on $\mathbb{S}^2$ with the property that the induced area (w.r.t $\omega$) of all the hemispheres is the same.

Is it true that $\omega$ is a scalar multiplication of the standard volume form induced by the round metric?

Comment: No, any symmetric measure (under $v \mapsto -v$) has that property.

Comment: Oh, you are right of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. Let $f:\mathbb{S}^2 \to \mathbb{S}^2$ be the antipodal map $x \to -x$. Then we are looking at the space

$$ \{\omega \in \Omega^2(\mathbb{S}^2) \, | \, f^*\omega=\omega\}.$$

This space is infinite dimensional. Here is a way to generate an arbitrary element in it: Take any form $\omega$ and define $\tilde \omega=\omega+f^*\omega$.

This is similar to the situation of [inverse-invariant metrics on Lie groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1622586/how-to-show-the-space-of-inverse-invariant-metrics-on-a-lie-group-is-infinite-di).

(This happens whenever we want a symmetry of finite order, we can always average of pullbacked copies).